# stack trace in Assembly 8051 with push and pop instructions

Tags: assembly, stack-trace, 8051

I'm new to Assembly language in 8051. The question I have is: 
[image]

I know the values at addresses at 40H, 41H, 42H, 43H, 44H, are 10H, 0DH, 10H, 10H, F0H.

But I don't know how one could get those values by hand. I know push first increases SP by 1 and then copy the data to address in the RAM specified by SP. However, I could get 40H has value 10H but don't know how to proceed afterwards.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You proceed by tracing the other following stack operations too, of course. Next is the `call`, that puts a return address on the stack (`100Dh`, which in little endian will be `0Dh 10h`) then you again have a `push acc` which writes `10h`, then a `push b` which of course writes `0F0h`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow ALL the subsequent instructions in your program that uses stack (and in the order those instructions are executed).

The stack using instructions in your program are:
1. push acc --- puts 10H onto the stack (at location 40h)
2. call --- puts the return address onto the stack (i.e. address 0x100D onto the stack in little endian order. So, 0Dh at location 41h and 10h at location 42h)

Now the jmp instruction doesn't get executed. instead, the control is transferred to a_x_b_plus1 because of the call instruction.

So, 
3. push acc --- puts again 10H onto the stack (at location 43h)
4. push b --- puts F0h onto the stack (at location 44h).